# Run uWSGI command in a Django docker container

Tags: django, docker

I have a django project that works with web sockets, so my question is, can I run a uWSGI command inside my python container?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/

CMD [ "uwsgi", "--http", "8081", \
               "--gevent", "100", \
               "--module", "websocket", \
               "--gevent-monkey-patch", "--master", \
               "--processes", "4" ]
```

This CMD isn't running, I also tried running it from docker-compose, but it didn't work too.

Comment: What error do you got?

Comment: @AlexC with this setup, there are no errors, the execution of this commands is not even showing in Docker. While doing this through docker-compose (right after runserver), it says 'uknown command uwsgi'

Comment: You should install uwsgi in your container first

Comment: @MikhailSidorov isn't it installing with pip? Or I have to do any extra stuff?

Comment: uwsgi should be in your requirements.txt, this way it will be installed before CMD run

Comment: @AlexC it is, I guess the problem is that I'm running uwsgi at a wrong place

Comment: @Desiigner If you have uwsgi in your requirements.txt it must be installed with  `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` command

Comment: How do you run docker? If I build a simplified version of your Dockerfile (`pip3 install uwsgi` instead or `requirements.txt`, and some lines commented) with `docker build -t somename .` and then run `docker run -it somename`, uwsgi starts with no problem.
You installing uwsgi globaly in your container by `pip3 install ...` so there shouldn't be a mess with paths / places

Comment: @AlexC sorry for confusion, yes you’re right, that’s happened to be a problem in build, I didn’t notice a little error there, so it couldn’t rebuild an image and it used the previous one, without uwsgi settings